# Using the value of an XML element in XSLT transform

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML file like this:

```
<Root>
  <Sensor xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <position_x>2170</position_x>
    <position_y>1830</position_y>
    <module_number>10</module_number>
    <disabled>false</disabled>
    <sequence_number>0</sequence_number>
    <id_number>0</id_number>
    <channel_number>10</channel_number>
  </Sensor>
</Root>
```

And I have an XSL file like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='1.0'>
  <xsl:template match='/'>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
      <xsl:for-each select="Root/Sensor">
        <g transform="translate(position_x,position_y)" id="S">
          <text x="118" y="20" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="18px" font-weight="bold" fill="black"><xsl:value-of select="Root/Sensor/sequence_number" /></text>
          <rect x="12" y="32" width="8" height="18" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
          <text x="23" y="97" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="16px" fill="black"><xsl:value-of select="Root/Sensor/id_number" /></text>
          <text x="23" y="117" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="16px" fill="black"><xsl:value-of select="Root/Sensor/channel_number" /></text>
          <text x="142" y="80" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20px" font-weight="bold" fill="black">S<xsl:value-of select="Root/Sensor/module_number" /></text>
        </g>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </svg>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is I want the value of position_x (2170) and position_y (1830), in my transform. But I can't work out how to put them there. It seems I'm not able to put

```
<xsl:value-of select="Root/Sensor/position_x" />
```

into the transform.

Is there a way to achieve this or am I going about this the wrong way?

EDIT:

If I try to have the line:

```
<g transform="translate(<xsl:value-of select="position_x"/>,<xsl:value-of select="position_y" />)" id="S">
```

I get the error: '<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is illegal in XML attribute values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as Martin Honnen correctly points out, you should remove `Root/Sensor/` from all the `value-of` elements because the current node inside the `for-each` is a particular `Sensor`, not the whole document:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sequence_number" />
```

Second, in the `transform` attribute, you should surround `position_x` and `position_y` with curly braces to mark them as expressions to be evaluated:

```
<g transform="translate({position_x},{position_y})" id="S">
```

So the XSL file should look like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='1.0'>
  <xsl:template match='/'>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
      <xsl:for-each select="Root/Sensor">
        <g transform="translate({position_x},{position_y})" id="S">
          <text x="118" y="20" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="18px" font-weight="bold" fill="black"><xsl:value-of select="sequence_number" /></text>
          <rect x="12" y="32" width="8" height="18" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
          <text x="23" y="97" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="16px" fill="black"><xsl:value-of select="id_number" /></text>
          <text x="23" y="117" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="16px" fill="black"><xsl:value-of select="channel_number" /></text>
          <text x="142" y="80" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20px" font-weight="bold" fill="black">S<xsl:value-of select="module_number" /></text>
        </g>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </svg>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your `for-each select="Root/Sensor"` the context element is a `Sensor` element so any paths inside of the `for-each` should be relative e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="position_x"/>`.

Comment: Hi Martin. If I put     <g transform="translate(<xsl:value-of select="position_x"/>,<xsl:value-of select="position_y" />)" id="S"> I get: '<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character. I'm not sure how I can format the XSL:value of to be put into the transform line.